# docker-compose up not listening on specified port

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I run `docker-compose up`, it tells me its listening on localhost port 5000, despite port 80 configuration in my `docker-compose.override.yml` file, and despite exposing port 80 in the `Dockerfile`.

I've also tried setting the port in `docker-compose.yml` but it still defaults to port 5000

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  myapp:
    image: me/myapp
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MyApp.API/Dockerfile
```

docker-compose.override.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  myapp:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

Dockerfile:

```
...

EXPOSE 80

...
```

What am I missing that would force `docker-compose up` to listen on the port specified in the yml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its important with what kind of configuration you start the ASP.NET application. You can do that by putting it into the environment like that:

*Dockerfile*

```
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:80
```

**Alternatively** you an also define it in your `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  myapp:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:80
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

Comment: that worked, thank you! follow up question: would i need to do something similar for the prod environment?

Comment: What do you mean by "similar"? You need to define somehow on which port the application should start. One way is doing that via environment variables, which is convenient to use in docker. Check out the documentation how to do that via configuration file: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: well if i simply build the project it will start on port 5000, based on the appsettings.json and appsettings.Development.json file

Comment: If you want to change that for your production environment in a similar matter then yes. Another way would be to define the `urls` parameter in you appsettings.json directly.

Answer (score 0):

The EXPOSE instruction in Dockerfile does not actually publish the port. It functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are intended to be published. To actually publish the port when running the container, use the -p flag on docker run to publish and map one or more ports, or the -P flag to publish all exposed ports and map them to high-order ports.

In your case all control is done via docker compose and I would not worry about seeing port 5000 as it is still going to be inaccessible.